# How to get quick documentation working with PyCharm and Pytorch

Tags: python, machine-learning, pycharm, pytorch

I'm running [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) on Windows 10, and installed [PyTorch](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/) following the getting started guide. Where I used [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/) and Anaconda to set up everything.

I can run the PyTorch tutorials from inside the PyCharm IDE without any problems. So I feel like I have a proper set up, but there aren't any intellisense documentations for any of the PyTorch APIs.

For example;

```
import torch

x = torch.randn(128, 20)
```

If I mouse over `randn` and press [CTRL+Q](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/inline-documentation.html) then PyCharm shows me a popup of the function definition without any documentation.

I'm expecting to see Python comments from the API documentation for that function:

https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html?highlight=randn#torch.randn

I'm a new beginner with Pytorch and Python, but this is something that I often have access to from inside the IDE with many other languages and libraries. So I feel like this should be possible to get working, but I can't seem to find any instructions on how to fix this.

Comment: did it work for you with keyboard short cut?

Answer (score 8):

I was able to get it working by doing the following:

> PyStorm 2019.3

Open the settings for external documentation:

> File / Settings / Tools / External Documentation

Add the following URL patterns:

```
Module Name: torch.nn.functional
        URL: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.functional.html#{element.qname}
```

```
Module Name: torch
        URL: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/{module.basename}.html#{element.qname}
```

Seems to work for most APIs but you have to trigger the quick documentation tool window. This won't show docs if you `CTRL+CLICK` something.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to get [Kite](https://kite.com/integrations/pycharm/). It has this feature (that I use intensively) called co-pilot where you can get python docs immediately. I don't know if it's Linux/Mac specific but works for any editor, nit just Pycharm.

<sub>It's just another solution</sub>

Answer (score 0):

PyCharm2022.1.x still cannot display torch(1.10) documentation.
@Reactgular 's answer is helpful. But the url that works for me is different.

Following the steps:
file --settings--tools -- external documentation -- add

Module Name: torch
URL/Path Pattern: [https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/{element.qname}.html#{element.qname}](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/%7Belement.qname%7D.html#%7Belement.qname%7D)

Actually the above steps only let the pycharm show a link. But it is better than nothing. just click the link and a default browser will open the documentation.
You can also specify a customized browser instead of the system default browser: file-- settings-- tools --web browsers and preview

[torch quick doc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZp2Y.png)

Answer (score 0):

I was about just to add a comment for Reactgular's solution but it turned out I didn't have enough "reputation" to do it.

For the torch.nn.functional module, I found it is more helpful to do this to jump directly to the detailed documentation for the function you are searching for.

```
torch.nn.functional
https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/{element.qname}.html#{element.qname}
```

But of course, this is not a stable page so I guess it may not work later, so be careful about it.